# .Net Core AWS Lambda function not flushing logs

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, logging, aws-lambda

I have set up a .NET Core AWS Lambda function using the AWS Toolkit Extensions's template project structure. The function works as expected. The only issue I have is that my logs are not always flushed before the application shuts down. I usually lose about one or two lines of logs. I am using AWS Cloudwatch to store my logs and hooking into the inbuilt .NET Core logging framework.

I believe the issue is that the logger pushes it's logs in batches rather than immediately sending them. The problem is that my Lambda is obviously finishing before the logger can send it's last batch, so some get missed.

I've tried reducing the batch push interval to one second but I'm still having issues. I also tried disposing the service provider I'm using in the hope that this would force the logger to flush it's logs but that doesn't seem to have helped either.

I've been unable to find a way to manually flush the logs from the .NET Core logger.

I don't really want to be adding anything like `Thread.Sleep` to the end of my function - it's messy and I really shouldn't have to do this.

Here is my code:

**Function entry:**

```
public class Function
{
    private readonly Startup startup;

    private ServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private ILogger<Function> logger;

    public Function()
    {
        startup = new Startup();
    }

    public async Task FunctionHandler(SendUnsentBrochuresRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        serviceProvider = startup.InitializeFunction();
        logger = this.serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Function>>();

        try
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation("Beginning function...");
            var service = this.serviceProvider.GetService<SendUnsentBrochuresService>();
            await service.Process(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex, ex.FullExceptionDetails());
        }
        finally
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation("Finished sending unsent brochure requests.");
            this.serviceProvider.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup:**
(Using `AWS.Logger.AspNetCore` nuget package)

```
public class Startup
{
    public ServiceProvider InitializeFunction()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        // Config
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var config = configBuilder.Build();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

        var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(config["AWS:AccessKey"], config["AWS:SecretKey"]);

        // Logging
        services.AddLogging(builder =>
        {
            var options = new AWSLoggerConfig()
            {
                Credentials = awsCredentials,
                LogGroup = config["AWS:Cloudwatch:LogGroup"],
                Region = "eu-west-2",
                BatchPushInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            };

            builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);

            builder.AddAWSProvider(options);
        });

        // Other stuff...

        // Function
        services.AddTransient<SendUnsentBrochuresService>();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library is not a good fit for Lambda due to the fact that it uploads the logs in a background thread. We do call that out in the README for the repo. https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#aws-lambda

Is there a reason you want to use this library versus using the logging built into Lambda to CloudWatch logs? If it is a preference for .NET Core API and configuration you can use `Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore` which will send the logs to the attached LogStream like `context.Logger.LogLine`

Comment: My main need for this is because I have various underlying libraries which have dependencies on the `ILogger` .NET class. These libraries are used for various applications which might not necessarily be Lambda functions so I don't want to be passing the LambdaLogger instance around and since it doesn't implement ILogger, I can't use it in my dependency injection. I will have a look at `Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore` as it sounds like this may solve my problem. Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: Should `Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore` work with `TestLambdaLogger`? I have an integration test for my Lambda function and I'm using the `Amazon.Lambda.TestUtilities.TestLambdaLogger` class but after running the test, the Buffer property is empty. I have followed the setup outlined here: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore

Comment: Thank Norm. This package works perfectly. I still haven't figured out if it's possible to get this working with my tests but I can live with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, I am not a .Net developer. I hope you are aware of AWS Lambda limitations. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Make sure the Function memory allocation and Function timeout are within the limits.

Make sure your AWS lambda has a role attached with permission to write logs in AWS Cloudwatch

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that the function has permission to write logs to Cloudwatch. It's only missing off the one or two lines of logs, not everything. Also, I have allocated 1GB of memory to my Lambda function which is more than enough for what it's doing. It typically only uses 100-200MB.