# Using return value from awaited method

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, async-await, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to understand `async` methods and `await`, I've got this simple example:

```
using (var client = new AmazonSQSClient())
{
    var sqsRequest = new SendMessageRequest()
    {
        MessageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(callProcessingRequest),
        QueueUrl = "https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/*****6014/W*****g"
    };

    LoggingHelper.Log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Calling SQS", context);

    var sqsResponse = await client.SendMessageAsync(sqsRequest);

    LoggingHelper.Log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sqsResponse), context)
}
```

When I run this, the logging of `sqsResponse` never happens, however if I change

```
var sqsResponse = await client.SendMessageAsync(sqsRequest);
```

to

```
var sqsResponse = client.SendMessageAsync(sqsRequest).Result;
```

Then it works as expected.

With it being an `async` method I guess I should be using `await` with it, but not sure why it's not working.

EDIT: Whole method as requested. Adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` didn't help.

```
public static async Task ProcessOutstandingDialplanItems()
{
    var context = new Context() { CurrentHandler = "PBXCallbacksLambdaFunction" };

    var callProcessingRequest = new CallProcessingRequest()
    {
        context = context,
        MethodToInvoke = "ProcessOutstandingDialPlanItems"
    };

    try
    {
        using (var client = new AmazonSQSClient())
        {
            var sqsRequest = new SendMessageRequest()
            {
                MessageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(callProcessingRequest),
                QueueUrl = "https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXX6014/WXXXg"
            };

            LambdaLogger.Log("Calling SQS");

            var sqsResponse = await client.SendMessageAsync(sqsRequest)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            //var sqsResponse = client.SendMessageAsync(sqsRequest).Result;

            LambdaLogger.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sqsResponse));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log(x.Message);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don’t call result. It can deadlock

Comment: If `await` doesn't work but `.Result` does, it could be some obscure problem related to the resuming thread not being the initial one, and your logging service relying on it. In which context is this code running ? C# console app ? ASP.NET ?

Comment: It's an AWS Lambda function (C# / .NET core)

Comment: What are you using for logging? Can it be something which depends on the current thread?

Comment: How are you using the `ProcessOutstandingDialplanItems` method? Are you `await`ing it asynchronously, or you are `Wait`ing it synchronously? Could you include that specific line in the question?

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586886/net-core-aws-lambda-function-not-flushing-logs

Comment: How do you call `ProcessOutstandingDialplanItems` function? Are you using `await` up to the entrypoint?

Answer (score 1):

From [AWS Logging .NET](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet#aws-lambda):

> ##### AWS Lambda
>
> These packages batch logging messages in a queue and send messages to CloudWatch Logs using a background thread. The use of the background thread means that **the messages are not guaranteed to be delivered when used in AWS Lambda**. The reason is because the background thread will be frozen once a Lambda event is processed and may not ever be unfrozen if more Lambda events are not received for some time.
>
> When using Lambda it is recommended to use either the ILambdaContext.Logger.LogLine or the Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore package.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are already using `Result` or `Wait` (or something which is calling your code) in one of the method before in application which has [`SynchronizationContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097471/what-does-synchronizationcontext-do) (classic ASP.NET, UI apps like WPF, WinForms, etc.). That is a "good" way to end up in deadlock. One thing you can try - adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the call:

```cs
var sqsResponse = await client.SendMessageAsync(sqsRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But much better course of action - [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Weird blog post. His first best practice is "just a hack"? (His words, not mine)

Comment: @DavidLibido yes, you can consider it as one. Also post author definitely knows his stuff, so I would recommend to take his opinion in account)

Comment: I'm sure he does  but I will not consider using these kind of "best practices" in my code.

Comment: @DavidLibido: Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in library code is a best practice. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlocks is a hack. Hopefully this clears that up.